# Having Multiple Tabs on the same page with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

Having some problems with very basic JQ tabs

I need to have 3 or 4 of the same tabs on the same page. I got this JQ code and it works for one tab although when I click on the other tabs the first tabs content change only.

Can someone please show me a work around to have this implemented.

This is the code im using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ul.tabs').each(function(){
var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');
$active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
$active.addClass('active');
$content = $($active.attr('href'));

$links.not($active).each(function () {
    $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
```

});

```
// Bind the click event handler
       $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
    $active.removeClass('active');
    $content.hide();
    $active = $(this);
    $content = $($(this).attr('href'));
    $active.addClass('active');
    $content.show();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

});

This is the HTML

```
 <div class="bluetabs"> 
  <ul class='tabs'>
    <li><a href='#tab1'>WEB DESIGN</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab2'>GRAPHIC DESIGN</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="bluetabContent"> 
      <div id='tab1'>
       ...
      </div>
      <div id='tab2'>
      ...
      </div>

  </div>
</div><!-- BLUE TABS -->

<div class="greentabs"> 
  <ul class='tabs'>
    <li><a href='#tab1'>WEB DESIGN</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab2'>GRAPHIC DESIGN</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="bluetabContent"> 
      <div id='tab1'>
       ...
      </div>
      <div id='tab2'>
      ...
      </div>

  </div>
</div><!-- GREEN TABS -->

<div class="redtabs"> 
  <ul class='tabs'>
    <li><a href='#tab1'>WEB DESIGN</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab2'>GRAPHIC DESIGN</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="bluetabContent"> 
      <div id='tab1'>
       ...
      </div>
      <div id='tab2'>
      ...
      </div>

  </div>
</div><!-- RED TABS -->
```

Comment: The html is missing. Please make a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Hi Updated with the HTML - Thanks

Comment: `id='tab1'` Id attribute should be `UNIQUE` in a html document

Comment: Awesome... thanks... what a dummy :) when you work with something too long you tend to overlook these stupid mistakes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your ID attributes Unique in a html document e.g [Ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

So in short , changing your tab ids to tab1, tab2, tab3 and tab4 will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

you can you  Jquery  tabs, it's can used multipe in one and work  without unique class can be the same class for all  your table.
https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

check  this and copy multiple time tabs but change the ID to  class and also  in jquery will work.